# How to bypass a unique ID get the child property of a snapshot.val() in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to query through a list of products in my Firebase database, and when I've queried through that list I want to retrieve the url of that product.

I'm already able to query through the list of products. When I use the following:

```
$scope.filterForResult = function(userResponse){
    this.query = cleatsRef
    .orderByChild('filter')
    .startAt(userResponse.color+"_"+userResponse.sex+"_"+userResponse.studs+"_"+userResponse.upper+"_"+userResponse.price)
    .endAt(userResponse.color+"_"+userResponse.sex+"_"+userResponse.studs+"_"+userResponse.upper+"_"+userResponse.price);
    this.result = this.query.on('value', function(snapshot){
    return resultProduct = console.log(snapshot.val());
   });
};
```

and when I respond with the following **userResponses**:
color="black",sex="male", studs="firm ground", upper="synthetic", and price="50", I receive the correct product, as an object:

```
"cleats":{    
  "adidas ACE 15,4 FG - Core Black - Matte Silver - White":{
    "brand":"adidas",
    "color":"black",
    "filter":"black_male_firm ground_synthetic_50",
    "price":50,
    "sex":"male",
    "stud":"firm ground",
    "upper":"synthetic",
    "url":"http://www.prodirectsoccer.com/US/products/adidas-ACE-154-FG-Mens-Soccer-Shoes-Firm-Ground-Core-Black-Matte-Silver-White-118537.aspx?"},"adidas ACE 15,4 FxG - Core Black - Silver Metallic - Solar Yellow":{"brand":"adidas","color":"black","price":50,"sex":"male","stud":"firm ground","upper":"synthetic","url":"http://www.prodirectsoccer.com/US/products/adidas-ACE-154-FxG-Soccer-Cleats-All-Ground-Core-Black-Silver-Metallic-Solar-Yellow-108740.aspx?"
  }
}
```

However, the next step I want to do is to retrieve the url of the product. How would I bypass the unique ID **adidas ACE 15,4 FG - Core Black - Matte Silver - White** in order to get to the property of **url** in Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here.

### A query returns a list of child nodes

Whenever you execute a Firebase query, the value will always be a list of children. Even if there only one result, it'll still be in a list of one.

So you need to handle that in your code.

```
var filter = userResponse.color+"_"+userResponse.sex+"_"+userResponse.studs+"_"+userResponse.upper+"_"+userResponse.price;
this.query = cleatsRef
    .orderByChild('filter')
    .startAt(filter)
    .endAt(filter);
this.result = this.query.on('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.val());
    });
});
```

### You cannot return data that is still being loaded

The second problem is that you're trying to return data that is still being loaded. That is not possible, and you cannot wait until it is loaded either (your users would not appreciate that).

To understand the flow of your code better, add these log statements:

```
console.log('before query');
this.result = this.query.on('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log('in query callback');
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.val());
    });
});
console.log('after query');
```

You'll see that the output is:

> before query
>
> after query
>
> in query callback

That is probably not what you expected. The reason for this ordering is that `on()` only *starts** loading the data. This may take some time, so the browser continues executing the code *after) the `query.on(...` statement. Then once the results are available, it invokes your callback function.

The solution can be many things. But since you're using AngularFire, it is most likely:

```
$scope.result = $firebaseArray(query)
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='child in result'>
```